# How to use only English in names with a local OpenStreetMap server?

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap

I have a local OpenStreetMap Server (Ubuntu + postgresql + mod_tile + mapnik). 
How to use only English language in names (or any Specific language) for all areas?

P.S. I understand that names store in tags and maybe for some areas it's not available.

**UPDATE** Can I change style file for mapnik to render tiles in specific language?

Answer (score 2):

There have been similar questions at [help.openstreetmap.org](http://help.openstreetmap.org) with different solutions, see:

- https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/7920/mapnik-street-name-generation
- https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/21784/render-place-name-in-two-languages-with-mapnik
- https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/20735/country-place-and-street-names-in-english-instead-of-local-language-for-my-own-mapserver

So you can choose between modifying the style, osm2pgsql or rewriting tags using lua.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup you will want to edit the queries to Postgres to choose the local name if available. See https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/21784/render-place-name-in-two-languages-with-mapnik for an example.

You will need to make sure that the tags are preserved when doing the import(s).